# IQ imbalance on quadrature signal

Tags: quadrature, software-defined-radio

Hi I am attempting to develop a reasonable IQ balance mechanism for a quadrature signal coming from a software defined radio.I can balance out the amplitude and phase differences at one frequency quite well, about - 80dBm.  However, over the typical span of my spectrum scope (192khz), there are differences at different frequencies.  Now I have determined that the differences are quite linear.  I could get away with doing a linear regression on a few points taken over the frequency range. But..
I am correcting the I and Q signals before the fast fourier transform.  In other words, in the time domain.  How do I bring this to the frequency domain?  I have the real and imaginary amplitude and frequencies of course before I plot them.  Can I use the same equations on the frequency values?
Thanks

Comment: If the phase offset is a linear function of the frequency (in the frequency domain), it indicates a fixed time delay (in the time domain).[a](http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/mdft/Linear_Phase_Terms.html); [b](http://www.dspguide.com/ch10/2.htm); [c](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/TimeDelay/TimeDelay.html); [d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/linear_phase); etc. You can correct a linear phase shift by a small delay in time before the FFT.

Comment: Yes I have determined however that the delay is a fraction of a sample so this complicates things considerably.